# Visualizing skewed data

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, seaborn

The following lines of code gives the plot but that is skewed towards left.

```
sns.distplot(fraud_false['Amount'],
             hist=False, color='darkblue',
             kde_kws = {'shade': True, 'linewidth': 3})

sns.distplot(fraud_true['Amount'],
             hist=False, color='darkred',
             kde_kws = {'shade': True, 'linewidth': 3})

plt.title('Density Plot')
plt.xlabel('Amount')
plt.ylabel('Density')
```

Taking log of data makes the distribution normal. But how to take the original values of data in x axis of the plot instead of these new log values?

Comment: How do readers run your code without having the complete data? Since you are new to Stack Overflow, take some time in reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to keep the data log-transformed but on the x-axis of your distplot you want to have xticks that are not on log-transformed scale?

Comment: @Sheldore sure sir.

Comment: Yes, I am talking of the same @sim

Comment: Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132262/12046409) about how one could create log tick-labels for log-transformed data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly:

You could either log-scale your entire axis. This will result in your bins in the distplot to also be log-scaled. Alternatively, you can log-transform your data and update your xticks to reflect the log-scale nature of your axis. Below shows this by example.

```
from scipy.stats import skewnorm
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sbs

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 5))
data = skewnorm.rvs(size=1000, a=5)
sbs.distplot(data, ax=ax[0])
sbs.distplot(data, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_xscale("log")
sbs.distplot(np.log(data), ax=ax[2])
ax[2].set_xticklabels([round(d, 1) for d in np.exp(ax[2].get_xticks())]);
```

[image]