# Plotting errorbar in log scale, negative value

Tags: python, matplotlib, logarithm, errorbar

I am trying to plot error bar in log scale. This is what I have been trying:

```
ax.errorbar(s, m1, std1)
ax.set_yscale("log", nonposy = "clip")
```

And this is what I got:

[image]

Does anyone have solution for this, it seems `nonposy = "clip"` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: What did you expect as a result?

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132262/12046409) might be useful

Comment: I plotted the same thing in matlab and did not have any problem, it just ignores the negative values and plot it (I use normal errorbar() code). I am wondering how matlab is doing that and there is anyway to do the same in python.

Comment: `ax.set_yscale("symlog")` might be helpful