# repeated y axis ticks in violinplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I want to plot the distribution with violinplot of a set of values between 1 and 800, I have used this code. I am very new to this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker as mticker
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

log_data = [[np.log10(d) for d in row] for row in [data['count']]]
print(log_data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.violinplot(data=log_data, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Why do I have three 10^0s?

[image]

This is my data:
[  8,   7,   5,   1,   2,   6,   5,   1,   2,  31,   9,  40,   9,
53,   4,   8,   3,   1,  46,   2,  18,   4,  17,  26,  17,   2,
19,  14,   2,  16,  35,  42,  22,   2,  19,  13,  59,  11,  69,
33,   2,   2,  24,  86,  16,  11,   7,   5,  18,  22,   1,   2,
16,  28,   3,   2,  12,  16,   1,   8,   1,   2,   5,   4,   9,
1,   1,   5,   1,   4,   5,   2,  11,  25,   6,  45,  64,   6,
2,  63,  26,   2,   3,   8,   3,  16,   8,   2,   2,  99,   2,
51,  43,   5,  53,  10,  19,  20,   6,   9,   1,   4,   1,  19,
4,   2,   3,   2,  77,   4,   7,   3,   2,   1,  81,  15,  50,
22,  58,  21,  10,   1,  18,   8,   1,  35,   2,  32,  18,  12,
11,   7,   5,  27,  29,   1,   2,   5,   1,   2,   3,   3,   1,
45,  22,   1,  12,   2,  21,   4,   1,  19,  27,  23,   3,   1,
21,   1, 124,  13,  17,   1,  18,  33,  23,   3,   6,   2,   8,
3,   1, 228,  28,   1,   1, 122, 868,  47,   2,   1,   9, 108,
10,   1,   5,  40,  43,   5,   2, 137,   9,  11,  19,  19,  11,
21,   8,   1,   6,   2,   3,   3,  26,  42,  14,   1,  14,  15,
3,  30,  17,   5,  17,   3,  38,  11,  54,   3,   1,   1,   3,
3,   7,   3,   1,   1,   5,   9,   1,   5,   4,   7,  35,   8,
10,   6,   6,   5,   3,  28,   2,   2,   5,  13,   6,   2,   4,
3,   2,   7,  52,  31,   1,   7,   7, 216,   4,  13,   6,  14,
4,   4,   5, 102,   3,  15,   4,  12,  48,   5,   9,   3,  10,
35,  36,   2,  10,   2,  55,  15,  17,   2,  19,  14,  14,  15,
5,   4,  11,   1,   1,  18,   4,  63,  63,  22,  37,   2,  22,
8,  22,   8,  20, 104,   3,   2,   6,  11,  20,   1,   3,  78,
2,   1,  52,  33,   2,   4,   9,   1,  27,   9,   4,   4,   2,
9,   9,   2,  24, 137,  12,   2,   2,   1,   6,  11,   8,   1,
20,  23,  75,   5,   1,  14,   3,  31,  15,   4,   2,  26,  50,
9,  75,  42,  14,   4,   1,   2,   9,  34,  25,  37,  53, 122,
28,  52,  22,   1, 109,   1,   1,  11,   1,  15,   2,   9,  32,
23,   5,   6,   3,   2,  51,   9,  12,  10,   7,   5,   2,   1,
311,  41,   1,   6,  13,   2,   5,  18, 105,  13,  17,   3,   9,
48,   2,  15,  18,  16,  77,  13,   3,   2,   2,   8,   1,   3,
4,  93,  23, 169,   1,  24,   2,   1,   8,  36,   1,   1,   1,
6,   3,   1,  25,   1,   2,  59,   2,   3,   3,   1,   8,   2,
1,   6,  15,   1,   7,  29,   4,   4,   8,  22,   5,  80,  16,
3, 147,  23,   6,  16,   1,   8, 530]

Using the set_yscale

```
ax.set_yscale('log')

sns.violinplot(data=first_issues_count, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: @JohanC I need them on the log scale.

Comment: @DRA, I think JohanC was getting to the point that you are not setting a log scale anywhere in your code.

Comment: Also, is it possible to share your dataset (or a small-ish subset that still creates the plotting error)? Trying to create my own (pulling from a normal distribution and plotting it on a log scale) comes out just fine, so it's hard to figure out what could be going on.

Comment: @ramzeek I have converted the data, also when I use set_yscale my plot doesn't look the way I want, the x-axis cut it, no curve on the bottom.

Comment: Without a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's hard to try to help.

Comment: @DRA, you can use `ax.set_ylim` to change your y-axis limits.

Comment: @ramzeek I added the data.

Comment: @JohanC 
 that answer is actually what I used to convert the data. But I get those three 10^0s if I change the range.

Comment: Your data have `np.log10(1)` which is 0. A log plot never goes to 0 until you reach 10**-infty. That is your problem.

Comment: Also, I would say one of the great things about a violin plot is it shows the pdf of the data. Plotting on a log scale makes it much harder to interpret visually, and so you are losing the power a violin plot provides over a simpler depiction such as  a box plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A logscale option for the violinplot is on the [roadmap for seaborn 0.12](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2258). Meanwhile, you can calculate the violinplot using the log10 of the _data and some formatting tricks, similar to [Violin Plot troubles in Python on log scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131839/violin-plot-troubles-in-python-on-log-scale).

The example code below shows how the formatting tricks could be adapted for your situation.  For comparison, a [`sns.boxenplot`](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/letter-value-plot.html) is added, which doesn't have problems with a real log scale.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.array([8, 7, 5, 1, 2, 6, 5, 1, 2, 31, 9, 40, 9, 53, 4, 8, 3, 1, 46, 2, 18, 4, 17, 26, 17, 2, 19, 14, 2, 16, 35, 42, 22, 2, 19, 13, 59, 11, 69, 33, 2, 2, 24, 86, 16, 11, 7, 5, 18, 22, 1, 2, 16, 28, 3, 2, 12, 16, 1, 8, 1, 2, 5, 4, 9, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 5, 2, 11, 25, 6, 45, 64, 6, 2, 63, 26, 2, 3, 8, 3, 16, 8, 2, 2, 99, 2, 51, 43, 5, 53, 10, 19, 20, 6, 9, 1, 4, 1, 19, 4, 2, 3, 2, 77, 4, 7, 3, 2, 1, 81, 15, 50, 22, 58, 21, 10, 1, 18, 8, 1, 35, 2, 32, 18, 12, 11, 7, 5, 27, 29, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 45, 22, 1, 12, 2, 21, 4, 1, 19, 27, 23, 3, 1, 21, 1, 124, 13, 17, 1, 18, 33, 23, 3, 6, 2, 8, 3, 1, 228, 28, 1, 1, 122, 868, 47, 2, 1, 9, 108, 10, 1, 5, 40, 43, 5, 2, 137, 9, 11, 19, 19, 11, 21, 8, 1, 6, 2, 3, 3, 26, 42, 14, 1, 14, 15, 3, 30, 17, 5, 17, 3, 38, 11, 54, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 3, 1, 1, 5, 9, 1, 5, 4, 7, 35, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5, 3, 28, 2, 2, 5, 13, 6, 2, 4, 3, 2, 7, 52, 31, 1, 7, 7, 216, 4, 13, 6, 14, 4, 4, 5, 102, 3, 15, 4, 12, 48, 5, 9, 3, 10, 35, 36, 2, 10, 2, 55, 15, 17, 2, 19, 14, 14, 15, 5, 4, 11, 1, 1, 18, 4, 63, 63, 22, 37, 2, 22, 8, 22, 8, 20, 104, 3, 2, 6, 11, 20, 1, 3, 78, 2, 1, 52, 33, 2, 4, 9, 1, 27, 9, 4, 4, 2, 9, 9, 2, 24, 137, 12, 2, 2, 1, 6, 11, 8, 1, 20, 23, 75, 5, 1, 14, 3, 31, 15, 4, 2, 26, 50, 9, 75, 42, 14, 4, 1, 2, 9, 34, 25, 37, 53, 122, 28, 52, 22, 1, 109, 1, 1, 11, 1, 15, 2, 9, 32, 23, 5, 6, 3, 2, 51, 9, 12, 10, 7, 5, 2, 1, 311, 41, 1, 6, 13, 2, 5, 18, 105, 13, 17, 3, 9, 48, 2, 15, 18, 16, 77, 13, 3, 2, 2, 8, 1, 3, 4, 93, 23, 169, 1, 24, 2, 1, 8, 36, 1, 1, 1, 6, 3, 1, 25, 1, 2, 59, 2, 3, 3, 1, 8, 2, 1, 6, 15, 1, 7, 29, 4, 4, 8, 22, 5, 80, 16, 3, 147, 23, 6, 16, 1, 8, 530])

sns.set_style('ticks')
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(16, 8))

sns.violinplot(y=np.log10(data), ax=ax1)
major_ticks = np.arange(np.floor(np.log10(data).min()), np.log10(data).max() + 1)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks(major_ticks, minor=False)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks([np.log10(x) for p in major_ticks for x in np.linspace(10 ** p, 10 ** (p + 1), 10)], minor=True)
ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter("$10^{{{x:.0f}}}$"))

ax2.set_yscale('log')
sns.boxenplot(y=data, ax=ax2)
ymin, ymax = ax1.get_ylim()
ax2.set_ylim(10**ymin, 10**ymax)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: violinplot on log scale and boxenplot]

Comment: Was this answer helpful?